# How to select clicked element using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="search-input" onclick="getSearch()">
              <input
                oninput="getPorts(value)"
                type="text"
                id="pick"
                name="pick"
                placeholder="Enter Pickup Location"
                required
              />
              <div class="autocom-box">
                <!-- dynamic portsData map box  -->
              </div>
            </div>
 <div class="search-input" onclick="getSearch()">
              <input
                oninput="getPorts(value)"
                type="text"
                id="dest"
                name="dest"
                placeholder="Enter Destination"
                required
              />
              <div class="autocom-box">
                <!-- dynamic portsData map box  -->
              </div>
            </div>
```

This is Js

```
let searchWrapper;
let inputBox;
let suggBox;

const getSearch = () => {
  searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-input");
  console.log(searchWrapper);
  inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
  console.log(inputBox);
  suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
  console.log(suggBox);
};
```

I am trying to get class selected based click as the class name is same (search-input) but here whichever div i click it always gets selected the 1st one. (In searchWrapper console.log it gives 1st div and its elements)

Can anyone tell me What am i doing wrong here so that i can get 2nd div and its elements if i click on 2nd div.

Comment: I know there's an earlier version of this question we should point this at, but I can't find a **clean** one.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".search-input")` returns the first matching result, which is going to be the same for all calls. Why not go with `event.target` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two answers for you.

#### Using modern event handling

I suggest you don't use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. There are multiple issues with them, but probably the most significant two are:

1. They can only call global functions.
2. The generated context for them is **very** complex, making it **very** easy to run into conflicts (for instance, if your function had the name `removeChild` or `appendChild` or in some cases `submit`, you wouldn't end up calling your function, you'd call a method on a DOM element instead).

Instead, look at using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Here's an example where the event handlers are directly attached to your `div` elements:

```html
<div class="search-input">
    <input
        oninput="getPorts(value)"
        type="text"
        id="pick"
        name="pick"
        placeholder="Enter Pickup Location"
        required
    />
    <div class="autocom-box">
        <!-- dynamic portsData map box  -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="search-input">
    <input
        oninput="getPorts(value)"
        type="text"
        id="dest"
        name="dest"
        placeholder="Enter Destination"
        required
    />
    <div class="autocom-box">
        <!-- dynamic portsData map box  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
const getSearch = (event) => {
    const searchWrapper = event.currentTarget;
    const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
    const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
    // ...
};

for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(".search-input")) {
    element.addEventListener("click", getSearch);
}
```

I only did the `div` elements there, but you'd want to do the `input` elements as well.

You might also look at [delegated event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

#### Continuing with `onclick` attribute

If you **really** want to keep using the `onclick` attribute, pass `this` into it:

```html
<div class="search-input" onclick="getSearch(this)">
<!-- −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^  -->
```

`this` in the context generated for `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers is the element the `onclick` attribute is on (the `.search-input` `div` in this case).

Then, in `getSearch`, search within that `div`:

```js
const getSearch = (searchWrapper) => {
    const inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
    const suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all stop using inline event listeners. Use `addEventListener` instead. To do so, grab a list of all search input wrappers and iterate over the list, adding a click listener to each and every one.

When you have done so, the handler function automatically gets passed the event object, which contains the `currentTarget` property holding a reference to the element the event listener is bound to. This then allows you to find *descendants of that element* using `querySelector` on it instead of `document`.

To access the event object, you need to define a parameter name in your handler function. I've used `event` in below example, but you can name it anything you like.

```js
let searchWrapper;
let inputBox;
let suggBox;

const getSearch = (event) => {
  searchWrapper = event.currentTarget;
  console.log(searchWrapper);
  inputBox = searchWrapper.querySelector("input");
  console.log(inputBox);
  suggBox = searchWrapper.querySelector(".autocom-box");
  console.log(suggBox);
};

for (const searchInput of document.querySelectorAll('.search-input')) {
  searchInput.addEventListener('click', getSearch);
}
```

```html
<div class="search-input">
  <input type="text" id="pick" name="pick" placeholder="Enter Pickup Location" required />
  <div class="autocom-box">
    1. abc
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search-input">
  <input type="text" id="dest" name="dest" placeholder="Enter Destination" required />
  <div class="autocom-box">
    2. def 
  </div>
</div>
```